how to plot multiple lines in one figure with different scale sizes
I want to plot multiple lines in one figure in which one of my lines has a larger scale size, but when I do so the changes in lines with a smaller scale size disappear. Therefore, I need to know whether it is possible to plot it so that I can see the differences in the lines with on a smaller scale too.
I attached my plot

Thank you in advance
I plotted my results by uploading the data and plot it by a simple plot method in python.

You can isolate this feature and use a twined axes. Can you do this manually? Also please provide a [mre]

See Plots with different scales

Thanks for the helps
I found that the Y-axis break would help for what I was trying to show in my plot.
Here I attached the corrected plot.
enter image description here

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
